# Add a rownumber based on the sequence of values provided

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, row-number

```
SELECT Code, Value FROM dbo.Sample
```

Output:

```
 Code     Value
 Alpha    Pig
 Beta     Horse
 Charlie  Dog
 Delta    Cat
 Echo     Fish
```

I want to add a sequence column by specifying a list of Codes and sort the list based on the order specified in the IN clause.

```
SELECT Code, Value FROM dbo.Sample
WHERE Code in ('Beta', 'Echo', 'Alpha')
```

I could declare a variable at the top to specify the Codes if that is easier.

The key is that I want to add the row number based on the order that I specify them in.

Output:

```
 Row   Code    Value
  1    Beta    Horse
  2    Echo    Fish
  3    Alpha   Pig
```

---

Edit: I realized after that my Codes are all a fixed length which makes a big difference in how it could be done.  I marked the answer below as correct, but my solution is to use a comma-separated string of values:

```
DECLARE @CodeList TABLE (Seq int, Code nchar(3))
DECLARE @CodeSequence varchar(255)
DECLARE @ThisCode char(3)
DECLARE @Codes int
SET @Codes = 0

-- string of comma-separated codes
SET @CodeSequence = 'ZZZ,ABC,FGH,YYY,BBB,CCC'

----loop through and create index and populate @CodeList
WHILE @Codes*4 < LEN(@CodeSequence)
BEGIN
    SET @ThisCode = SUBSTRING(@CodeSequence,@Codes*4+1,3)
    SET @Codes = @Codes + 1
    INSERT @CodeList (Seq, Code) VALUES (@Codes, @ThisCode)
END

SELECT Seq, Code from @CodeList
```

Comment: that select won't necessarily produce those values in that order without an ORDER BY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the only 2 ways I've seen work accurately:

The first uses `CHARINDEX` (similar to Gordon's, but I think the WHERE statement is more accurate using `IN`):

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample
WHERE Code IN ('Beta','Echo','Alpha')
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(Code+',','Beta,Echo,Alpha,')
```

Concatenating the comma with code should ensure sub-matches don't affect the results.

Alternatively, you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample
WHERE Code in ('Beta','Echo','Alpha')
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN Code = 'Beta' THEN 1
  WHEN Code = 'Echo' THEN 2
  WHEN Code = 'Alpha' THEN 3
END
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7e31/1)

[Updated Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5431/4) with sub-matches.

Comment: I should have specified that the code fields are all 3 characters and unique as I can see how it could change the results.  Maybe there is even a shorter way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for any lenght code list.
Create table with self incrementing field and code. Insert in given order. Join tables and order by ...

Some details. Please read [this](http://dinushasblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/split-strings-in-mysql.html). You will find there function that creates table with auto increment field from string (delimited by commas), i.e.

```
mysql> call insertEngineer('dinusha,nuwan,nirosh');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> select * from engineer;
+----+----------+
| ID | NAME     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | dinusha  |
|  2 | nuwan    |
|  3 | nirosh   |
+----+----------+
```

Next join your Sample table with result of above. GL

Comment: I like the idea, but perhaps you could provide sample code, including dynamically populating a temporary table or table variable so that the order can vary.

Comment: I'm going to try this one. I like the simplicity of specifying the data fields as I plan to change the fields and order around during testing. Thanks.  And I think I will modify the function to assume a comma delimiter to simplify it more.

Comment: No. are you facing any issues?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Comment: At the bottom of the thread there is equivalent http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/looking-for-substring_index-of-mysqls-function.18395/

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use Values as Table Source

```
SELECT Row, Code, Value
FROM [Sample] s JOIN (       
                      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS Row, Match
                      FROM (VALUES ('Beta'), 
                                   ('Echo'), 
                                   ('Alpha'))
                      x (Match)                             
                      ) o ON s.Code = o.Match
ORDER BY Row
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7854/1)

Comment: `ORDER BY(SELECT 1)` can be replaced by `ORDER BY 1` (or even better `ORDER BY 42`)

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name thx, but when I replaced by ORDER BY 1 this give me error 5308:Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know SQL Server does not support this (sounds like a bug to me as the SQL standard doesn't allow a column reference by position at that place anyway). Apparently sorting by a constant is not allowed at all (`order by null` is also not accepted).

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to do this using string functions:

```
declare @list varchar(8000) = 'Beta,Echo,Alpha';

with Sample as (
    select 'Alpha' as Code, 'Pig' as Value union all
    select 'Beta', 'Horse' union all
    select 'Charlie', 'Dog' union all
    select 'Delta', 'Cat' union all
    select 'Echo', 'Fish'
)
select * from Sample
where charindex(Code, @list) > 0
order by charindex(Code, @list)
```

If you are worried about submatches, just do the "delimiter" trick:

```
where @list like '%,'+Code+',%'
```

Comment: works as long as the words in the words list don't have any sub-matches. e.g. won't work 'beta,echo, betabeta, alpha', but a clever technique.

Comment: Yes, that's very clever, and should work assuming there are no possible sub-matches as @MitchWheat mentioned.  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a lil bit of change to whats been done above to include the rownumbers as well.

```
SELECT  CASE   
          WHEN Code = 'BetaBeta' THEN 1  
          WHEN Code = 'Beta' THEN 2  
          WHEN Code = 'Alpha' THEN 3  
        END CodeOrder,  
        *  
FROM Sample  
WHERE Code in ('BetaBeta','Beta','Alpha')  
ORDER BY CodeOrder
```

> [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fc88/2)